# Answering with modified CSS vs complete CSS

Tags: discussion, answers, code-formatting

So, I'm still a little new around here.

When I correct someone's CSS, I only include the relevant lines of code that I have updated or added (unless my solution doesn't work with some of the other lines of code).  I do this because IMO: it's more clear, it's easier to explain each line, and it makes the answer more reusable.

I've seen several questions where the same answer is given with and without the irrelevant code.  The answers with the irrelevant code seem to be preferred.  I would guess this is because it's easier for the asker to copy/paste the code as a block.

Are there any opinions or conventions around which approach is better?  Should we prioritize the convenience of the asker or future reusability?

Comment: Personally I'd prefer just the edited/fixed lines. 1) Makes it easier to see what has been changed, and 2) Makes it **harder** for the OP to just copy paste it in, it will help them ultimately see what's different and hopefully learn something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The answers with the irrelevant code seem to be preferred. I would guess this is because it's easier for the asker to copy/paste the code as a block, which I understand.

This. You don't *have* to fully fix OP's code, rather explain what they did wrong and optionally show the lines you fixed.

Answer (score 9):

You should prioritize future reusability. Convenience of the asker in expense of usefulness or readability for the general public is not a good thing to have.

The entire point of code-based answers to questions about non-working code is to show what exactly it is that should be changed in order to resolve the issue plaguing the non-working code. Especially for declarative languages such as HTML and CSS, where LOC can often be in the scores or hundreds for something deceptively simple, having more irrelevant code serves little more than to cloud the important part of the answer, the part that a reader needs to pay attention to.

The worst kind of answer is one that completely regurgitates the code in the question, changes a few lines, yet offers no explanation whatsoever of what was changed. Having just the context-relevant lines of code on the other hand would at least be self-explanatory to some degree (although of course, explaining the solution and the rationale always helps).

Answer (score -2):

I would only show the code that directly fixes the problem, as well as a clear concise explanation of why that code fixes that particular problem. If you show all of the code it can often times confuse the person who answered the question because they can not find what you fixed.

Comment: What does this answer add that isn't already covered by the previous answers?

Comment: I was trying to draw emphasis on the fact that showing all the code can easily overwhelm the OP. This was not emphasized in earlier posts. I think that a shorter more clear showing of the code will allow the OP to understand what is written better.